# Sharepoint 2010 server licenses

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a question regarding Sharepoint 2010 server licenses,

The site I'm trying to set up will be using formed based authentication and validating users through a database that will be running on SQL server, so no ActiveDirectory users.

I'm hoping to register 1 URL, and have users visit the site to get the public content, the site will also have a private section that you have to login to in order to access the private info (that’s where the database above comes in to play).

Our question regarding licenses is that most models I've seen have 2 servers, 1 public, 1 private each with a different license, is it not possible to set up 1 server, have 2 sites on the server (1 public, 1 private) and in that scenario only use up one license?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All servers in the farm has to be licensed equally. And if you are going to license it for internet usage - it's just the server license, ie no need for CALs.
In your case; you can host multiple sites/web applications on the same server using the same server license